# why my app not navigating to next screen after fetching data from API in react native

Tags: react-native, navigation

I am new to react native. and I have created two screen from first screen I receive data from API and I load that data in params and send it to next screen But when I tap on Button Not navigation just alert json response.

here is my code

```
class Browse extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ListView:[]
    };
  }
   ListView = () => 
    {
   
   AsyncStorage.multiGet(["application_id", "created_by"]).then(response => {
   
    fetch("https://xyz.tech/Android_API_CI/data_for_user", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify([{ id:response[1][1], application_id:response[0][1]}]),
    })
      .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())
     
        .then(function(response)  {
          alert(JSON.stringify(response))
          this.setState({
            ListView: response
           })
       
      
           alert(JSON.stringify(response))
          
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
       
            
            this.props.navigation.navigate("ListView", {
             
              
            });
         
      
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
     
    })
    }
  render() {
    const { profile, navigation } = this.props;
    const tabs = [""];
    return (
    
          <Block flex={false} row space="between" style={styles.categories}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                //onPress={() => navigation.navigate("FormItems")}
                onPress={() => this.ListView()}
              >
      </Block>
    );
  }
}
```

please ignore this. I am new to react native. and I have created two screen from first screen I receive data from API and I load that data in params and send it to next screen But when I tap on Button Not navigation just alert json response.I am new to react native. and I have created two screen from first screen I receive data from API and I load that data in params and send it to next screen But when I tap on Button Not navigation just alert json response.

Comment: Can you share your navigation component so I can deep dive into that and help you?

Comment: just tell whats the problem . weather it is API Data param sending problem or navigation problem

Comment: Here it seems ok but have you added Stack.Screen "ListView" component in stackNavigator ?

Comment: yes i have add it

Comment: so its API data sending probelm ???

Comment: Add comment on the alert code and see is it navigating to another screen?

Comment: not its not navigatin

Comment: Are you getting any error or warning ?

Comment: no nothing happen

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.setState')   this error coming in consol

Comment: Ok There is any error because you have to bind the methods that updating the state as in the class component this keyword refers to the current object with means it will find the setState method from the TouchableOpacity which will cause error

Comment: ok i will see thanku

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

We have to bind the methods that updating the state as in the class component this keyword refers to the current object which means it will find the setState method from the TouchableOpacity which will cause an error.

Have a try by adding some code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        ListView:[]
    };
    this.ListView = this.ListView.bind(this)
}

ListView = () => {
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(["application_id", "created_by"])
        .then(response => {
            fetch("https://xyz.tech/Android_API_CI/data_for_user", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify([{ id:response[1][1], application_id:response[0][1]}]),
            })
            .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())
            .then(function(response)  {
                alert(JSON.stringify(response))
                this.setState({
                    ListView: response
                })
            
                alert(JSON.stringify(response))
                
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
            
                this.props.navigation.navigate("ListView");
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error : ", err.message)
        })
    }
```